Cannot connect Ant Media to standalone MongoDB
I am running Ant Media in a docker container. I want to connect it to a MongoDB. I have followed the documentation  on how to run the start.sh file to connect to the DB.
When I bash into the container and use the following command:
root@df9a4c1eb559:/# /usr/local/antmedia/start.sh -m standalone -h my_mongo_ip mymongoadminuser secret
It tells me that DB type is redis:
root@df9a4c1eb559:/# /usr/local/antmedia/start.sh -m standalone -h my_mongo_ip mongoadmin secret Mode: standalone DB type is redis 172.17.0.2 df9a4c1eb559 Running on  Linux Starting Ant Media Server Selected libraries: (270 items) Root: /usr/local/antmedia
I have also confirmed that the container can reach the mongoDB because I installed the mongo client inside the container and connected it successfully.
